# allocatemem() function in Pari for perl

Tags: perl, memory, stack-size

I was generating random numbers using the Crypt::Random module for perl which relies on Math::Pari, a perl interface for Pari/GP, and got this error when trying to generate a 1.5M digit number:

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>perl -MCrypt::Random=makerandom_itv -E "say makerandom_itv(Lower => '10^1499999', Upper => '10^1500000')" > num_1500000.txt
PARI:   ***   the PARI stack overflows !
        current stack size: 4.0 Mbytes
  [hint] you can increase GP stack with allocatemem()

C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Perl Scripts>perl scripts1.pl
"use" not allowed in expression at scripts1.pl line 6, at end of line
syntax error at scripts1.pl line 6, near "use Math::Pari
use Math::PariInit "
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at scripts1.pl line 7.
```

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Math::Pari
use Math::PariInit qw( primes=12000000 stack=1e8 );
use Crypt::Random
```

I had guessed the allocatemem() function was a Math::Pari function, but it is not. Does anyone know to change the GP stack size to 8.0 Mbytes using a script compared to one-liner? Thanks.

Problem with the stack to 1e+32

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents\Perl Scripts>perl scripts1.pl > BIGINT1500000.txt
PARI:   ***   the PARI stack overflows !
        current stack size: 0.0 Mbytes
  [hint] you can increase GP stack with allocatemem()
Compilation failed in require at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Math/PariInit.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at scripts1.pl line 6.
```

Script:

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# use Math::Pari;
use Math::PariInit qw( stack=1e32 );
use Crypt::Random qw(makerandom_itv);

say makerandom_itv(Lower => '10^1499999', Upper => '10^1500000');
```

Comment: (Incidentally, you're missing a `;` at the end of `use Math::Pari`.)

Comment: My answer below now has sample code and has been tested. It works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to reach for `allocatemem()`, which is listed as one of the functions that can be used but aren't directly supported, see [this in Math::Pari](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Pari/Pari.pm#Directly_accessible_from_Perl).

Instead, from the [INITIALIZATION in Math::Pari](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Pari/Pari.pm#INITIALIZATION)

> When Math::Pari is loaded, it examines variables $Math::Pari::initmem and $Math::Pari::initprimes. They specify up to which number the initial list of primes should be precalculated, and how large should be the arena for PARI calculations (in bytes). (These values have safe defaults.)
>
> Since setting these values before loading requires either a BEGIN block, or postponing the loading (use vs. require), it may be more convenient to set them via Math::PariInit:
>
> ```
> use Math::PariInit qw( primes=12000000 stack=1e8 );
> ```

See the (short) page for [Math::PariInit](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eilyaz/Math-Pari-2.01080900/PariInit.pm).

A complete example

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# use Math::Pari;
use Math::PariInit qw( stack=1e8 );
use Crypt::Random qw(makerandom_itv);

say makerandom_itv(Lower => '10^1499999', Upper => '10^1500000')";
```

Running `script.pl > BIG_num.txt` generates a `1.5Mb` file with the number (in 11 minutes).

In this way the stack size is set at compilation. See the first link for changing it dynamically.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with Math::Pari modules, I added more code to the post.

Comment: @J.Linne Is this all you tried -- a one-liner?  These are complicated environments, I'd suggest putting together a small script to try it -- unless you did. (Btw, this is not how you load options for modules in a one-liner.) Write a script which loads all modules you need, including the line from my answer.

Comment: I work mostly with the one-liner, I put the one liner command in a script and ran it and still get the same problem w 3M digits.

Comment: @J.Linne  You put one-liner in what script? A shell script?  Again, I'd suggest that you write a small Perl script, where you enter all needed `use ...` statements, including the one from my answer.  Then the simplest code that you need for the test.  You can then call that from your shell script, instead of the one-liner.  (I can't test write now.)

Comment: DESCRIPTION ^

use Math::PariInit takes the same arguments as use Math::Pari with the addition of :primes=limit and :stack=bytes which specify up to which number the initial list of primes should be precalculated, and how large should be the arena for PARI calculations.

The arguments primes and stack cannot be specified if Math::Pari is already loaded.

Comment: To extend your script to stack=1e+32, gives me an error.

Comment: My goal of extending the script is to generate a number at lest 1B digits (1000M digits) reasonably quick, I do not generally care of how much memory is used.

Comment: @J.Linne  Let's say that 1Mb is a million bytes. That's 10^6. A gigabyte is then 10^9.  So a terabyte is 10^12. Then 10^13 is ten terrabytes, 10^14 is a hundred (no hard disk that big). There is probably not enough memory in all of the world's computer for 10^32.  It is hard to understand just how large that is.

Comment: @J.Linne  Let's attempt an estimate.  Let's say that one computer has (on order of) 1Gb, so 10^9.  There is an estimate that around 2014 there were around [2 billion PC's in the world](https://www.reference.com/technology/many-computers-world-e2e980daa5e128d0).  That's again an order of 10^9, times a Gb each brings us to 10^18.  Even if allow that it is still a, say, 100 times as much, we are only at 10^20.

Comment: I tried to increase the stack size so that a 1e+9 digit number can be generated in 11 min. Would you know if this is possible? I've notice that at the stack size in your script is good up to about 3M digits before taking hours or days to generate larger numbers.

Comment: @J.Linne  These are already pretty large numbers.  Given that the example in their documentation uses 1e8, ten times more may still be OK ... but soon enough you'll be pushing it and then all kinds of limits come out of woodwork.  Once you hit some hard limit things slow down dramatically, it can't really work anymore. When that happens depends on implementation and architechure but I'd expect that you can't go much further from the example they give.  I don't know.  You may want to go to some compiled tools designed for what your ultimate purpose is and read all documentation that they offer.